# Tridion translation management options

Tags: sdl-tridion, translation-manager

I am trying to understand the process to translate content manged in SDL Tridion and determine if Lionbridge is able to work with Tridion. Please let me know if anyone has used LionBridge with Tridion and how does it work?

Comment: I don’t have experience with this directly, but heard of people using content porter exports for translation. If the content gets packaged back correctly then you could import it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tridion has an add-on product called Translation Manager that allows content to be sent to its own translation software (TMS, WorldServer, etc.) and then monitored and retrieved. Unfortunately, Translation Manager isn't compatible with other, non-SDL translation systems such as LionBridge.

However, Tridion is extensible and has the Core Service API for accessing content and a supported mechanism for extending the (Anguilla) GUI, so you could write a custom connector.

Some things you may need to consider include:

1. How the content is sent for translation. Will this be single items of content (components) or a group of items (e.g. from a Tridion bundle)? How will this be done within the Tridion GUI?
2. How will the system get updates about the progress of the translation? Will the be pulled (periodically) from the translation system or will LionBridge push the information back as the translation status updates?
3. How will progress be reported back to the Tridion editor? Will there be email notifications and/or some kind of dashboard
4. Do you need some kind of audit logging?
5. Etc.

If you're looking to do this kind of custom connector, then I'd suggest that you'd need a reasonable amount of experience customising Tridion.